# import a python file into json file

Tags: python, json

I have a python file (`abc.py`) where all constants are defined. Now, I want to assign those constants in a JSON file. Once the values are assigned in the JSON file, I want to be able to convert it to an object.

For example:

```
abc.py
  val1 = 10
  val2 = 20

info.json
   import abc as C #which should be a *.py file

   {
     c1  = C.val1    #from python file
     c2  = C.val2 
   }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What you can do is have all your values in a `dictionary` and convert it to a `json`

Answer (score 0):

Your json file is just a specially formatted text file and you can't do import there, at least for simple cases.

You have to write a different function/program to create the json from the constants in your py file.

The dictionary creation needs to be worked on. You could start by playing with the below code.

```
def py_constants_to_json(output_file_name='info.json'):
    import abc as C
    import json
    const_dict = {
         'c1'  : C.val1,    #from python file
         'c2'  : C.val2 
       }
    with open(output_file_name,'w') as outf:
        json.dump(const_dict,outf,indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never name your file like abc, due to abc is built-in module in Python. Let's name it like something like my_python_constant.py

```
import my_python_constant
from operator import attrgetter
import json

variable_names = [s for s in dir(my_python_constant) if not s.startswith('__')]

my_dict = {variable_name: attrgetter(variable_name)(my_python_constant) for variable_name in variable_names}

print(json.dumps(my_dict))
```

And then you got a json string:

```
{"val1": 10, "val2": 20}
```

You can store is anywhere or file you like.